# Using Parameters in ALTER TABLE ...Add default statement

Tags: sql-server

I cannot use a parameter to set a default value for a column probably due to its properties as a variable, the error was:

The name "Mart" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

How can I convert a variable value to a constant or any better way to assign a value(a value of a parameter) to a column? Thanks a lot

```
declare @database varchar(100)

SET @database='Mart'

create table #temp 
(
    name varchar(256),
    [rows] int,
    reserved varchar(90),
    [data] varchar(90),
    index_size varchar(90),
    unused varchar(90),
    delta_date datetime default getdate()
) 

alter table #temp
add databese varchar(100)

declare @sqlstring1 nvarchar(500)

SET @sqlstring1 = N'ALTER TABLE #temp ADD DEFAULT "'+@database+'" FOR    
database'

exec sp_executesql @sqlstring1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE temp ADD DEFAULT '''+@database+''' FOR ......
```